# Add a button in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hello guys I'm using full calendar for calendar in a couple of my modules. In one module I have a requirement that the clients wants to add a button with the today and the left right button. Now one way to do is to customize the plugin but then I will have to add another file of full calendar for the other modules which is not good. So can you guys please tell me how can I accomplish this feature.

Here is what I'm trying to do: screencast.com/t/wbCSlBwgsSRU

and the HTML of the button is : 
  `<div class="padding-left-30"> <a href="<?= base_url()?>apps/calendar/calendarShow" class="btn  btn-primary" > Details </a></div>`

It would be a great help

Comment: I don't understand... adding a left, right and today button is done by setting the `header` option ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/c8kucp3j/1/)). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to add a another button with them

Comment: You don't have to modify the plugin to  remove or add custom buttons to the full calendar. You can  customize the buttons when you initialize it in jQuery. Can you post a picture of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Then use [`customButtons`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/)

Comment: HEre is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do: http://screencast.com/t/wbCSlBwgsSRU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys I was able to find the answer to my question. Now what I did was I placed the button as @Mottie told me to do in his answer and then inside that buttons js I used `window.location.href` and gave the url to it. Now I do not know if it's correct or not but this solution worked for me smoothly

Answer (score 3):

No extra modules are required. Use the [`customButtons` option](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/) to add another button to the [`header`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/c8kucp3j/3/))

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next, today, details',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    customButtons: {
      details: {
        text: 'Details',
        click: function() {
          alert('Show details!');
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It triggers a call to a controller which renders a view. Now if we look at here and try to do what I want to do it will go through a ajax call ??

Comment: Replace the `alert('...');` with whatever code you want. That includes ajax calls, or whatever.

Comment: Now currently my button is like this and on it's click a whole page reload takes place and a new view is rendered

`<div class="padding-left-30"> <a href="<?= base_url()?>apps/calendar/index" class="btn  btn-primary" > Details </a></div>`

I can't understand how to do it over here since in this case I'll have to make a ajax call which is not right in my case I think since a whole new page has to be rendered not just a piece of page

Comment: Oh, you're adding a link inside the button? That may be the reason. What exactly are you trying to do? Also, `<?= base_url()?>` won't render since we're working on the client side now.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do. The place where this calendar is going to be has a small version of calendar in which a person can just see the events not get a detailed view on them but when someone clicks this button it takes them to a brand new page which is only showing the calendar and all the events in it but here a person can click on the event to get the detailed information of a event

Comment: if there is any kind of ambiguity feel free to ask

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like the `<?= base_url()?>` needs to be removed.... make the link use a relative path to the page.

Comment: `<?base_url() ?>` is important because that will make the starting path to my website. like `www.facebook.com/messages` so `base_url` will be making `www.facebook.com`

Comment: I understand that, but as I said that will not be defined since it is being used *after* all the content has loaded on the client-side. Use a relative path that is based on the calendar page.

Comment: ahan. I see well then what will I do next